# Command-Line Email for Microsoft Office365 for use with Request Tracker (After BasicAuth Is Retired)

Tags: linux, imap, rt, exchange-basicauth

We use getmail (http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) to retrieve email from Microsoft Office365 accounts and shuttle them into Request Tracker (RT - https://bestpractical.com/request-tracker). Since Microsoft has announced the end of BasicAuth and has not released a method for doing OAUTH2 with IMAP, does anyone have a solution for letting an automated process retrieve email in Linux?

I need to be able to retrieve new messages and move them into RT. Getmail supports OAUTH2 but only with Gmail (and only using IMAP as the transport). Does anyone have a solution or workaround?

Comment: Microsoft uses ADAL, which is a variant or extension of OAuth2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries.  It is quite involved though.